# Asa Firewall Handle multiple Networks?

Tags: cisco-asa

I'm not familiar the the ASA Firewall devices but can i have 3 different networks on one device?

Three different ip ranges and be able to route different information on certain ports between them?

[image]

Neither Wifi lan must be able to see each other, BYOD AND Public Wi-Fi routed to internet only.

Clinical services to it respective connection Only.

Comment: The ASA can certainly route to different IP ranges on different interfaces.  If you could add a diagram and some more specifics on the solution you're trying to implement, we could provide more detail on how the ASA may or may not be the best fit for you.

Comment: a tip: don't limit your question with a "yes or no" structure ;)

Comment: Which ASA, what model and licenses are you trying to buy?  This is not as simple as what's assumed in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple answer to your question is "yes". Almost all of your diagram is fairly straightforward. The only possible catch is your "Clinical Services" setup. You can only have one route to 0.0.0.0/0 in a typical ASA configuration, so if Clinical Services is supposed to have a separate internet connection from the other networks, then you can't do that with one ASA unless you have an ASA that does virtual firewalls (I think that's the 5515 and up but you might have to go to the 5525). It might be more cost effective to just use two 5505s if you don't have a huge number of devices. Also, the virtual firewall configuration creates all kinds of caveats and different behavior on the ASA line.

When you set this up, you will have to manually configure dynamic NAT for all inside VLANs past the first.

Comment: I was not planning to use vlans, but use physical lans, and this is due to policies enforced that are out of my control

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the ASA can easily do this.  You have your choice of using physical interfaces for each of your networks, or you can save some money by using VLANs on a single interface.  You can also do some combination of the two.

You can create policies to restrict traffic any way you want.  Based on your diagram, though, you might have to do a little re-addressing.

Comment: Could you advise on whether the cisco ASA 5505 would be ok for this or should i go higher into the 5510?

Comment: @user31891 Can you give me some idea of your bandwidth requirements?  How big is your Internet connection?

Comment: Internet Connection is not set in stone as yet. We could Connect to our 10meg line or set up a new one. But if it helps we will be using the cisco 2600 series aironet devices that can handle 450mbps throughput, should we need it

Comment: Either the 5510 or 5512, depending on the bandwidth required for your clinical services network.

Answer (score -4):

I'm not that great with firewalls but I do know the ASA's allow you to create multiple contexts which I believe is more equivalent to a VLAN or VRF. How many contexts I'm not sure but it can be done.